# TCPDF Image doesnt show off normal

Tags: php, image, pdf, tcpdf

Im working on a PDF. I just wanted to change the logos so I changed the Image and on the first site I get the new image in correct size so but in the second pdf the image is very large.....

Here the line : `$this->Image('images/logo.jpg', 160,12.0,30 );`

Comment: 12.0 are u sure? Why float?

Answer (score 0):

I find it screws up if I used the same image twice.  Best practise is to use an image only one time in a PDF.  Make a copy of it under a different name if you are going to use it again.